# JQuery client's recommendations box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello im trying to make client's recommendations box for a studio site,
which is basicly its a slider of text.
My problem is that i cant trigger it to change the text.
When i firstly wrote it it was based on a timer of 5 seconds but my costumer wanted it with pause/unpause buttons. I tryied to do that but it didn't work so well so I suggested him that i'll make next/prev buttons. As I said before, the problem is, I think triggering the function.

That is my code:
JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/E2R5m/3/

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var suggNum = 0;

    var suggTitle = new Array(
        "by: 1", 
        "by: 2", 
        "by: 3", 
        "by: 4", 
        "by: 5"
    );

    var suggText = new Array(
        '1', 
        '2', 
        '3', 
        '4', 
        '5'
    );

    suggEdit(suggNum);

    function suggEdit(suggNum){
        $("#SuggStringTitle, #SuggStringText").hide().fadeOut();
        $("#SuggStringTitle").html(suggTitle[suggNum]);
        $("#SuggStringText").html(suggText[suggNum]);
        $("#SuggStringTitle, #SuggStringText").show().fadeIn();
    };

    $("#suggNext").click(function(suggNum){ suggNum=suggName+1; suggEdit(suggNum); if(suggName>4){suggName=0;} });
    $("#suggPrev").click(function(suggNum){ suggNum=suggName-1; suggEdit(suggNum); if(suggName<0){suggName=4;} });
});
```

buttons:

```
<button class="SuggCon" id="SuggNext"> Next </button>
        <button class="SuggCon" id="SuggPrev"> Prev </button>
```

Thanx!!!

Comment: Please create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so that we can at least understand what is it that you are trying to do.

Comment: Move the suggEdit function outside of the document ready block..

Comment: I'v mooved it but nothing is showing in the box

Comment: Added a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/E2R5m/2/

Comment: What's `suggName`? Also, you use `$("#suggPrev")` but the ID is `SuggPrev`.

Comment: I meant suggNum, Fixed

Comment: But still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed: **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/E2R5m/4/)**

You were putting your suggNum variable as a parameter in the click functions of next/prev which was causing it to pass the wrong variable to your suggEdit function. Then you also were running the if check within the click events after calling the suggEdit function when it should be done before.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var suggNum = 0;
    var suggTitle = new Array(
        "by: 1",
        "by: 2",
        "by: 3",
        "by: 4",
        "by: 5");
    var suggText = new Array(
        '1',
        '2',
        '3',
        '4',
        '5');
    suggEdit(suggNum);
    function suggEdit(suggNum) { console.log(suggNum);
        $("#SuggStringTitle, #SuggStringText").hide().fadeOut();
        $("#SuggStringTitle").html(suggTitle[suggNum]);
        $("#SuggStringText").html(suggText[suggNum]);
        $("#SuggStringTitle, #SuggStringText").show().fadeIn();
    };
    $("#SuggNext").click(function () {
        suggNum = suggNum + 1;
        if (suggNum > 4) {
            suggNum = 0;
        }
        suggEdit(suggNum);

    });
    $("#SuggPrev").click(function () {
        suggNum = suggNum - 1;
        if (suggNum < 0) {
            suggNum = 4;
        }
        suggEdit(suggNum);
    });
});
```

Comment: That's because you're using `.show()` before `.fadeIn()`. You can't fade in something if it's already being shown. Just remove the `.show()` from `.show().fadeIn()`.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to upvote answers on SO you think are helpful, and accept the ones that solve your problems.